# Selecting Rows between two specific date (Not Hardcoded)

Tags: sqlite

I have this code:

```
sqldf("SELECT  account_id, Cash_Payment
       FROM table1
       WHERE created_time BETWEEN MIN(DATE(transactions.created_time))
       AND MAX(DATE(transactions.created_time))")
```

but it does not work for me.

I would like to create a query of the `cash_Payment` by the user from the date of creating the account and till 7 days i.e. `Cash_Paymnent` in 1st week after creating the account for individual users.

Please let me know how the date manipulation can be done i.e

```
MIN(DATE(transactions.created_time)) +7days
```

Comment: How are the records in the `transactions` table related with the records in the `table1` table?

Answer (score 0):

probably you need to use:

```
MIN(DATETIME('transactions.created_time','+7 day'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this:

```
SELECT  account_id, Cash_Payment
       FROM table1
       WHERE created_time
       BETWEEN DATETIME(transactions.created_time) AND DATETIME(transactions.created_time,'+7 day')
```